# Joint probability distribution question

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A regular tetrahedron has four faces of different colours: blue, red, green and yellow. The
tetrahedron is repeatedly rolled. In each roll the four faces are equally likely to occur.
Let the random variable G denote the roll in which the green face occurs for the first time, and
let the random variable Y denote the roll in which the yellow face occurs for the first time.
Compute P(Y > n) and P(Y > n, G > n).

I obtained Y~ Geometric(1/4) and P(Y>n)=(3/4)^n, which makes perfect sense so far. However, the solution for P(Y > n, G > n)= (1/2)^n which doesn't make sense to me.

I had two guesses: P(Y>n, G>n)=P(Y>n)*P(G>n) [by independence] and so is equal to (3/4)^(2n)
Second guess was: P(Y>n, G>n)=P(Y>n)*P(G>n|Y>n)=P(Y>n)*P(G>n *intersection* Y>n)/P(Y>n)= P(G>n *intersection* Y>n) = P(Y>n, G>n)=P(Y>n)*P(G>n) [by independence]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "*By independence*"  Why would you think that the event that $Y>n$ is independent of the event that $G>n$?  It should be obvious that it is not, since if we were to continue further, $P(Y>n,G>n,B>n,R>n)$ is very obviously zero, not $P(Y>n)\times P(G>n)\times P(B>n)\times P(R>n)$ which is nonzero.  Obviously... at least one of the colors had to have been rolled on the first roll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need more than $n$ rolls to see the first yellow, and you need more than $n$ rolls to see the first green, then what do you know about the colors for rolls 1 through $n$?

Comment: Thinking about it this way makes sense. Since the first n rolls were not yellow and were not green, they must have been a sequence of blues and reds. The probability of getting either a blue or a red in a single roll is 2/4=1/2, and we shall have n rolls of having either blue or red, and so (1/2)^n.

Comment: However, is there a way to obtain (1/2)^n from P(Y > n, G > n)?

Comment: @jeff123 $P(Y>n,G>n)=P(Y>n)\cdot P(G>n\mid Y>n) = \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n\cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n=\left(\frac{2}{4}\right)^n$ where the conditional probability was calculated directly by imagining that since no yellow was rolled in the first $n$, that the die "*effectively had only three equally likely sides during this time instead of four*", one of which was green.

Comment: I think JMoravitz has given the correct answer. Notice also that the second guess in your original question was essentially a repeat of your first guess, except that you made a detour in the middle.

Comment: Thank you!! Can't believe I complicated it so much